# External Memory Trace PIN Tool

Tags: intel-pin

I tried using PIN tool to capture the memory trace. But, the PIN website says the addresses include all memory reads and writes.

I would like to capture the external memory addresses generated by a program. These addresses are the ones which are generated after cache accesses and hence correspond to physical address in DRAM.

Can you please let me know if I can capture the external memory address trace? I wanted to know if this is already available and if so, please point me to the source.

I saw the question: [Getting physical address in pin tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114260/getting-physical-address-in-pin-tool)

It says about conversion from virtual to physical. But, I want to get the trace of addresses after cache is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Just like any other piece of software, Pin can't tell whether the load/store instruction hit/missed in the cache or not.

The best you can do with Pin I think is to write a cache simulator (you can take a look at the one which comes with Pin - `pin-x.y/source/tools/SimpleExamples/dcache.cpp`) and record the accesses (i.e., addresses) which missed in the simulated cache. This won't be accurate for many reasons but it can be useful depending on your needs.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127802/using-intels-pin-tool-to-count-the-number-of-cache-hits-misses-in-a-program) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504314/7388892) discuss a similar point by the way.